# Get an array of years, months and weeks between two dates

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have this function that returns an array of years, months and days but I need to replace the days with weeks, so each month array will contain the weeks. Its not that easy.

```
$start_date = '2007-03-24';
$end_date = '2009-06-26';

year_month($start_date, $end_date);


//Returns an array containing the years, months and days between two dates
public function year_month($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
    $end = new DateTime( $end_date);
    $end->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); //Add 1 day to include the end date as a day
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); 
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    $aResult = array();

    foreach ( $period as $dt )
    {
        $aResult[$dt->format('Y')][$dt->format('F')][$dt->format('j')] = $dt->format('D');
    }

    return $aResult;
}
```

Currently results in:

```
 [2013] => Array
    (
        [October] => Array
            (
                [15] => Tue
                [16] => Wed
                [17] => Thu
                [18] => Fri
                [19] => Sat
                [20] => Sun
                [21] => Mon
                [22] => Tue
                [23] => Wed
                [24] => Thu
                [25] => Fri
                [26] => Sat
                [27] => Sun
                [28] => Mon
                [29] => Tue
                [30] => Wed
                [31] => Thu
            )

        [November] => Array
            (
                [1] => Fri
                [2] => Sat
                [3] => Sun
                [4] => Mon
                [5] => Tue
                [6] => Wed
                [7] => Thu
                [8] => Fri
                [9] => Sat
                [10] => Sun
                [11] => Mon
                [12] => Tue
                [13] => Wed
                [14] => Thu
                [15] => Fri
                [16] => Sat
                [17] => Sun
                [18] => Mon
                [19] => Tue
                [20] => Wed
                [21] => Thu
                [22] => Fri
                [23] => Sat
                [24] => Sun
                [25] => Mon
                [26] => Tue
                [27] => Wed
                [28] => Thu
                [29] => Fri
                [30] => Sat
            )

        [December] => Array
            (
```

I need something like this :

```
[2013] => Array
  (
    [October] => Array
        (
            [0] => week 1
            [1] => week 2
            [2] => week 3
            [3] => week 4
            [3] => week 5
```

Comment: Your comment says "1 month interval", but you've set the interval as `P1D`, which is still one day. Months are a funky beast anyways. Jan 31 + 1 month should "theoretically" produce Feb 31, which is an invalid date. Would you want Feb 28/29 (if leap year), or March 2nd/3rd?

Comment: This currently accounts for leap years due to the DateTime function.

Comment: @user794846: I'm not really sure what you mean by `I need to replace the days with weeks`. Could you add the expected results to the question?

Comment: @OlivierH: Huh? There *is* code in the question and the asker demonstrates *some* understanding of the problem.

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, that's why you just asked him to complete his question... And what a "good understanding of the problem" we got here, I quote : "Its not that easy.". Seriously, he comes here, says "I want It, it's not easy" without telling us what he tried to do. This is just against SO rules.

Comment: @OlivierH I have updated my question with current and expected results. I have tried adding $dt->format('W')] into the array at certain points but I cant output the results Im looking for.

Comment: Are you wanting week of the year, or week of the month?

Comment: What about the border cases? if a week starts in one month but ends in another should it be inserted into both months or just the month were it starts? what if your start date starts in the middle of a week but that week starts in the previous month? etc?

Comment: @Ben week of the year

Comment: Then change the `D` in `= $dt->format('D');` to a `W`.

Comment: @jasper Just allow the weeks to cross months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're wanting but, hey ho.

```
$start_date = '2007-03-24';
$end_date = '2009-06-26';

print_r(year_month($start_date, $end_date));


//Returns an array containing the years, months and week numbers between two dates
function year_month($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
    $end = new DateTime( $end_date);
    $end->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); //Add 1 day to include the end date as a day
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1W'); //Add 1 week
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    $aResult = array();
    foreach ( $period as $dt )
    {
        $aResult[$dt->format('Y')][$dt->format('F')][] = "Week ".$dt->format('W');
    }

    return $aResult;
}
```

Will return

```
Array
(
    [2007] => Array
        (
            [March] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week 12
                    [1] => Week 13
                )

            [April] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week 14
                    [1] => Week 15
                    [2] => Week 16
                    [3] => Week 17
                )

            [May] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week 18
                    [1] => Week 19
                    [2] => Week 20
                    [3] => Week 21
                )

            [June] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week 22
                    [1] => Week 23
                    [2] => Week 24
                    [3] => Week 25
                    [4] => Week 26
                )

            [July] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week 27
                    [1] => Week 28
                    [2] => Week 29
                    [3] => Week 30
                )
        )
)
```

[Full array](http://3v4l.org/tGOqs)

Comment: Thanks this may be what I am looking for, Ill need to apply it to my chart to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This function should do it, i use strtotime instead of the DateTime classes though

```
function year_month($start_date,$end_date){
    $current_date = strtotime($start_date);
    $end_date = strtotime($end_date);
    $out=array();
    while($current_date<=$end_date){
            $out[date("Y",$current_date)][date("F",$current_date)][date("W",$current_date)][]=date("D",$current_date);
            $current_date=strtotime("+1 days",$current_date);
    }
    return $out;
}

print_r(year_month("2007-03-24","2009-06-26"));
```

Comment: Why would you prefer `strtotime()` over `DateTime`?

Comment: Im sure DateTime is better but im used to working with strtotime and unix timestamps so it feels and reads more naturally to me. So i use it

Comment: I would prefer DateTime.

Comment: @user794846: If you want help, please be specific and address the questions that were asked in the [comments above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124349/get-an-array-of-years-months-and-weeks-between-two-dates#comment29989963_20124349).